# Can I filter find/replace to only search header files in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, header-files, replace

I am using Find and Replace in Visual Studio 2010.  Currently, I can filter the search to only look in:

- the current document
- the selection
- all open documents
- the current project
- the entire solution
- the current block

These are some great filters, but I would like to search only in header files.  Is there a way to search only in header files?

I am currently using [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html) to search and accomplish this externally to Visual Studio.  Is there a way to search in Visual Studio.  Plugins are acceptable answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use filters, use file types instead (maybe combined *with* filters). Open the `Find Options` section in the "Find In Files" perspective of the Find and Replace dialog.

For example, you can search all *.h files within the solution. Or all *.h files found under folders `c:\my_projects;c:\work_projects` (the filter drop-down allows multiple folders).

Comment: Great! This option only appears in the "Find in Files" dialog perspective (using Ctrl+Shift+F instead of Ctrl-F, or Edit->Find and Replace->Find in Files).  I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted if you just specify that your answer is using the Find and Replace with the "Find in Files" option, not just the standard dialog you get with Ctrl+F.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your message. I see you fixed it for me. :)